# Translation of this script to English please?

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, calligraphy

Translation of this script to English please?

[image]

Comment: Seems like  袁稼(壹? or 堂?)寫彩  翠(捽?)軒

Comment: Hi Tang Ho :) Thank you.. do you know what the may mean in english? 

Answer (score 1):

it’s “袁稼堂寫於翠梧軒”; the seal is the character “袁” (u+8881)

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=袁](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E8%A2%81)

the meaning roughly is: mr (袁), named (稼堂), sketched (寫) in (於) a place named (翠梧軒)

have fun :)

Comment: A sidenote: 写 is short for 写意, which is a technique of Chinese paintings. When I was learning 写意画 of Chinese painting, my master always told me to sign with 写, even though I'm actually painting rather than writing.

Comment: @lilysirius  yes, you’re right  寫 should be 寫意, or 寫生; i edited the answer 